# Linear interpolation is not working as expected

Tags: c++11, dictionary

I have a map that represents the values of a coefficient Y for a given range of temperatures. I'm trying to get the `coeff_Y` whenever the input key `designTemp`falls anywhere between the upper and lower limits of keys. I was able to get the three cases: a) when the value of the input `designTemp` is below the first key then `coeff_Y` is the first value, b) if the value of the input `designTemp` is beyond the last key then `coeff_Y` is the last value and c) if `designTemp` matches a key then the `coeff_Y` becomes the corresponding value. The case if the key falls anywhere within the key range is not working. The code showing the failed attempt of interpolation is shown below. Please note that I'm not a programmer, I'm a piping engineer just trying to write my own programs and trying to become proficient at coding with C++. Also, if there is any better solution please show so.

```
`cout << "\n Enter design temp. in degF: ";
float designTemp;
cin.clear(); cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); cin >> designTemp;

map<float, float> ferriticsteels_Y = { {900, 0.4}, {950, 0.5}, {1000, 0.7} };

if (ferriticsteels_Y.find(designTemp) != ferriticsteels_Y.end())
{
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y[designTemp];
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}
if (designTemp < ferriticsteels_Y.begin()->first)
{
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y.begin()->second;
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}
if (designTemp > ferriticsteels_Y.rbegin()->first)
{
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y.rbegin()->second;
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}

auto lower = ferriticsteels_Y.lower_bound(designTemp) == ferriticsteels_Y.begin() ? ferriticsteels_Y.begin() : --(ferriticsteels_Y.lower_bound(designTemp));
auto upper = ferriticsteels_Y.upper_bound(designTemp);
float coeff_Y = lower->second + (upper->second - lower->second) * float(designTemp - lower->first)/fabs(upper->first - lower->first);

time_t rawtime_end;
struct tm * timeinfo_end;
time(&rawtime_end);
timeinfo_end = localtime(&rawtime_end); 
cout << "\n" << asctime(timeinfo_end);

cout << "\nEnter any character and hit enter to exit: ";
char ans;
//cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); cin >> ans;...giving error at 'max()'
cin.clear(); cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); cin >> ans;

return 0;}`
```

Comment: For `std::map`, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` return the same iterator. They could only return different ones for containers like `std::multimap`, that allow ranges of equivalent values. You want to interpolate between `lower` and `std::next(lower)`

Comment: @Erik, the interpolation formula was based on one of your posts, can you please take a look? @ Igor Tandetnik I still don't get it. BTW, I revised the nesting of the if statements. Is a nest of three ifs

Comment: Correction - interpolate between `lower` and `std::prev(lower)`. `lower_bound()` gives you an iterator to the first (smallest) element greater than or equal to the argument. A previous element then must be less than the argument. So those are the two points of reference you need to interpolate between. Again, `upper_bound()` is of no use to you.

Comment: @ Igor, it works the way I had it. I just forgot to add a cout for looking at the interpolated value at the last else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. I just was making stupid mistake. It only required to revise the nesting of the if-statements and to add a `cout` for looking the interpolated value at the last `else`. Below is the code which works as expected:

`#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"`

`#include <Windows.h>`

`#include <map>`

`int main()`

`{`

```
SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("PipeTran™_v0.1"));
system("CLS");
system("color F1");

time_t rawtime_start;
struct tm * timeinfo_start;
time(&rawtime_start);
timeinfo_start = localtime(&rawtime_start);
printf(asctime(timeinfo_start));

cout << "\n Enter design temp. in degF: ";
float designTemp;
cin >> designTemp;
map<float, float> ferriticsteels_Y = { { 900, 0.4 },{ 950, 0.5 },{ 1000, 0.7 } };
if (ferriticsteels_Y.find(designTemp) != ferriticsteels_Y.end()) {
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y[designTemp];
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}
else if (designTemp < ferriticsteels_Y.begin()->first) {
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y.begin()->second;
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}
else if (designTemp > ferriticsteels_Y.rbegin()->first) {
    float coeff_Y = ferriticsteels_Y.rbegin()->second;
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}
else {
    auto lower = ferriticsteels_Y.lower_bound(designTemp) == ferriticsteels_Y.begin() ? ferriticsteels_Y.begin() : --(ferriticsteels_Y.lower_bound(designTemp));
    auto upper = ferriticsteels_Y.upper_bound(designTemp);
    float coeff_Y = lower->second + (upper->second - lower->second) * float(designTemp - lower->first) / fabs(upper->first - lower->first);
    cout << "\n Y: " << coeff_Y << endl;
}

time_t rawtime_end;
struct tm * timeinfo_end;
time(&rawtime_end);
timeinfo_end = localtime(&rawtime_end);
cout << "\n" << asctime(timeinfo_end);

cout << "\nEnter any character and hit enter to exit: ";
char ans;
cin.clear(); cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); cin >> ans;

return 0;
```

}